# Download data underlying plotly graph in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, r-plotly

I am using plotly in Rmarkdown.
When I plot a graph, id there a way to download the underlying data ?

```
library(plotly)
x <- c(1:100)
random_y <- rnorm(100, mean = 0)
data <- data.frame(x, random_y)
p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~random_y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
```

Typically in the plot above I would like to get the data data.frame in some csv format

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not a standard functionality of plotly. But you could add a DT::datatable to your Rmarkdown, since that does come with export buttons:
https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html#buttons

Comment: thanks that's what I do now but that's not really as slick

Comment: What about this: https://yihui.name/en/2018/07/embed-file/

Comment: @DavidKlotz yes ! that's fine, you can make an answer of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed the CSV file into your Rmarkdown HTML using this function: [yihui.name/en/2018/07/embed-file](http://yihui.name/en/2018/07/embed-file).